# Unable to get SQL Server connection object

Tags: java, sql-server

I wrote a simple code to connect to SQL Server database and to does a simple select statement, this code runs successfully on my local machine over VPN but when I deploy the same code in the servers, then my code is stopping at getting the DB connection object.

It is not even throwing any timeout exception, so I thought of a port issue and checked using telnet which is successful. Can anyone please suggest why this might happen? I am able to get connection object of the same DB from my local machine over VPN.

```
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        String connectionUrl = props.getProperty("DBURI");
        Connection conn=null;
        System.out.println(connectionUrl.trim());
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl.trim());
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev The code is a simple connection string to SQL DB , Thats the reason I havent posted ,and now I have , So now if you got something then please post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with the sqljdbc jar file , Used any 32 bit one , After replacing the jar , everything worked fine. Thanks